# Should I provide a summary of all answers as a self-answer to my question? Or do it some other way? Or not at all?

Tags: answers, discussion, summary

We usually get several answers to our questions. Quite often there will be more than one correct answer, as well as lots of interesting comments and discussion about the topic. Although there is already accepted answer I find useful (mainly for others) to provide an answer which is the **summary of all answers**.

Could you give me your comments on that? Keeping in mind that,

- Such summary would help me (and hopefully others) to understand more about my question and the accepted answer.
- I'm not after reputation (points).
- It was suggested somewhere not put answer in the question itself.

You can find [the prototype here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2126673/hash-assignment-when-key-value-are-stored-in-an-array-ruby).

Comment: maybe I insert the summary of answers below the original question

Comment: @Shog9: thank you for nice title.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to deal with questions answered by the OP in the question instead of in an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108969/best-way-to-deal-with-questions-answered-by-the-op-in-the-question-instead-of-in)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess, after choosing a selected answer, you could update your question outlining all of the useful information from the other answers

Comment: But don't be surprised if you get accused of rep-whoring and receive downvotes for this behavior...

Comment: Not if you updated your own question (rather than an answer)

Comment: (I know I'm commeting on an old post here, so sorry about that) This seems a bit weird given that question posts are for questions (and not answers) and answer posts are for answers.

Answer (score 4):

Some people get irritated when people post answers that merely re-hash the existing answers.  If you have nothing new to add, vote up the good answers so that the 'summary' is merely the top few answers.

Comment: @Pollyanna 'jerk''passv-agg: it won't be the summary,it would be the most voted answer/s

Comment: @Radek - that's the point.  Why do you need a 'summary' when the highest voted answers are likely the best and most relevant material?  Or, in other words, what is the problem you are trying to solve?  How will duplicated information help any users out?  In the past it's actually irritated me to see repeat information - I start skimming, then wonder if I'm missing anything because someone decided to say the same thing that is already given in another answer.

Comment: there is no problem... I personally find this summary helpful so I wanted to do it but ... I can see that 'community' doesn't have to like it. I am **really thankful** for all answers I got so I want to be part of this community. If most of you don't like the idea of summary. Well I won't do it. I'm happy with that. PS summary will in most cases contain more info that the answer with most up-votes. It looks like I won't do it ...

Answer (score 1):

Creating a new answer summarising the others is a good idea from the perspective of people who view the question, later.

But wouldn't there be a tendency for readers to upvote the answer? If they do, *you* get the reputation.

I think it's better to modify the question as Farseeker suggested.

Comment: If it was CW then it would be rep-less.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the point of a summary - I can read the answers myself.

Unless, of course, there's some reason I'm not going to read the answers myself, like if there are too many answers. In this case, a summary might be welcome, if it's kept up to date.