# User answered own question - but not as an answer

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, self-answer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to deal with questions answered by the OP in the question instead of in an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108969/best-way-to-deal-with-questions-answered-by-the-op-in-the-question-instead-of-in)

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11225927/html5-video-will-not-loop-on-android-devices) the OP has both defined the question and the answer **within the question box**.

Would this be a flaggable scenario, or something I should edit (by posting the answer myself)?

I doubt this would be a close.  So what would the best way forward be?

Answer (score 6):

I've left a comment to the OP on the question.

We can do a few things here:

1. Educate the OP; guide him towards the relevant FAQ sections.
2. Edit the post to separate the question and answer portions, so the answer is re-posted as community wiki.
3. Perhaps flag it as 'not a question', although there *is* a problem there that could be answered, if there wasn't an answer there already..

Comment: not  agree  on  your  second  point because if we remove the answer from question then we are depriving other users of the solutions by removing the solution from question if question is not answered

Comment: Does the FAQ cover answering your own questions yet? If not, general guidance might still help.

Comment: you are right @simchona but only if the question is answered not like the question which OP linked and meanwhile martijn updated the answer appropriately now

Comment: @Devjosh - For #2 I'd post it as a Community Wiki answer if the OP doesn't respond to a comment asking them to do so within a day or two

Comment: @flexo seems reasonable :)

Comment: I like the CW idea, updated the answer.

Comment: Now it's been closed that throws a spanner in the works for the "answer it yourself" comments

Comment: Yup, in this case the moderator decided it did fit the 'not a real question' bill anyway. I think that with a little editing it could have been saved. *shrug*.

Answer (score 4):

In a perfectly fair world you should comment saying "hey, post this as an answer" and wait for the asker to respond. This requires a level of dedication I wouldn't expect out of most users at all.

If the info is good, it should be posted as an answer. Edit out the non-question bits and post an answer containing the information. Polish it up and include any helpful information you can to make it an answer of your own, or make your answer community wiki so it doesn't look/feel like you're doing it just for the rep (or both, whatever you want).

In the end it's more important that the question is answered in the proper format, don't worry so much about who's "right" it is to post that answer. There's no reason to do the whole internet a disservice just to give the asker a chance to answer their own question. Just be sure to let them know what's up so they understand the situation and can self-answer properly in the future if need be.

Comment: this is a good case for community wiki, so that you don't have to take credit for someone else's work.